# Issue escaping single quote in iOS with stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:widthString

Tags: iphone

```
 NSString *test =  @"d'escape";
 NSLog(@"%@", [test stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"\'"]);
```

prints me this

```
2010-10-25 15:10:54.833 MyApp[7136:207] d'escape
```

What am I doing wrong ? I want to get this :

```
2010-10-25 15:10:54.833 MyApp[7136:207] d\'escape
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`\` itself is a special character in C. You need to escape it in the source.

```
[test stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"\\'"]
//                                                           ^^
```

Comment: I thought it was something stupid I was missing ^^ Thanks a lot