# NSFetchRequest fires NSInvalidArgumentException when query ontains apostrophe

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-data, nsfetchrequest

When I create query, that contains apostrophe, I got error:

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format
>   string "SELF.sale.ID == 0 AND ((SELF.dam contains[cd] 'Michael's') OR
>   (SELF.name contains[cd] 'Michael's') OR (SELF.purchaserLocation
>   contains[cd] 'Michael's') OR (SELF.purchaserName contains[cd]
>   'Michael's') OR (SELF.sire contains[cd] 'Michael's') OR (SELF.vendor
>   contains[cd] 'Michael's'))"'

I have tried to replace single apostrophe with two apostrpohes but still got same error.
When the query does not contain apostrophe, everything is going fine.
Thanks

Comment: Post your code where you construct the `NSPredicate`.

Comment: It was necessary to replace apostrophes with escapes apostrophes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I have to replace single apostrophe with escape string \'

Answer (score 0):

Actually here is the real solution :
[Issue escaping single quote in iOS with stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:widthString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014861/issue-escaping-single-quote-in-ios-with-stringbyreplacingoccurrencesofstringwid)

You need to put 2 `\`, because `\` is a character, and therefore needs to be escape to.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you surround the format placeholders in your format string with single quotes when using [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat]. These quotes aren't needed.

WRONG Example:

```
NSPredicate *myPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = '%@'";
```

CORRECT Example:

```
NSPredicate *myPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@";
```